# cURL not working - PHP

Tags: php, curl

I want to connect this site (https://ais.usvisa-info.com/en-ae/niv/users/sign_in) with cURL in PHP but blank screen is displayed and no error.
where is the problem?

Thanks

CODE:

```
<?php
function login($url, $data){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
    fclose($fp);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($login);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($login);
    unset($login);
}
?>

<?php
    echo login("https://ais.usvisa-info.com/en-ae/niv/users/sign_in", 'utf8=✓&authenticity_token=TEST&user[email]=test@yss.com&user[password]=12345&recaptcha_challenge_field=TEST&recaptcha_response_field=TEST&commit=Sing In');
?>
```

Comment: Try to add  
`display_errors(1);`
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`
to enable error output.

Comment: `return curl_exec ($login);` returns from the function ...so further lines will not execute. 
also there is a `captcha` which can't be retrieved by any method

Comment: @Riad I want to break recaptcha with DeathByCaptcha but the page is blank.

Comment: @seboettg I added, did not matter the page still is blank.

Comment: i just run on phpfiddle and see the web page as response...

Comment: @Riad Yeah woks in phpfiddle! I don't know but why does not work in localhost?! I installed xampp!

Comment: see `echo phpinfo();` in a test file and see if cURL is enabled

Comment: @Riad cURL support enabled and cURL Information 7.40.0

Comment: try to fetch any website with simple request

Comment: @Riad I've tested several sites page opens but Google did not open, I got an error in Google.

Comment: write the error and output of `curl_getinfo()` to view the responses...

Comment: Error: 405. That’s an error. The request method POST is inappropriate for the URL and curl_getinfo($login, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) return 0.

Comment: use `echo curl_getinfo($login)` before `unset` and print the array() you get.

Comment: Array ( [url] => http://google.com [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => 0 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 0 [local_ip] =>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121053/discussion-between-mohammad-and-riad).

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing out the result of login. login returns curl_exec($login). Since you called `curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);`, it will return the result on success and `FALSE` on failure. The result is probably an empty string if you do not have an error (take a look at the server logs to be sure).

Read more about the return value [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php).

By the way, `return` finishes the `function` and any further lines after that are completely irrelevant. Please, store the result of `curl_exec` into a local variable and return that at the end of the `function`.

Comment: code is already there and ok. You may test if you can fetch any other website (google.com) by using cURL.

Comment: @Mohammad, my answer tells you what you need to do with the code you pasted into the question. I prefer not to write code now, as I am very busy and do not have time to test it.